# dt~react-router error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'HistoryModule'

Tags: typescript, react-router, typescript-typings

I tried to download the React-Router typings definition using `typings install --save --global dt~react-router`, but my code will still not compile because the HistoryModule referenced by typings/globals/react-router/index.d.ts does not exist.

Earlier I was recommended to go with `typings --save react-router`, but although this includes the dreaded "HistoryModule", it is missing other key typing definitions for properties which the React Router elements typically have (missing onChange property of Route element props). Is there something else from typings that I need to download to get this to work? Also, how can I tell if I need to download multiple other global typings definitions to get a different one to work, because I'm not aware of any way and the typings command does not appear to understand if a global typing definition depends on other modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

from https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/9928

> The CLI tells you that there's been references stripped, it is up to the user to make sure they get installed. This is because references are not an adequate dependency system.
>   [image]
>   `typings install dt~react-router/history --global`

Answer (score 0):

> Is there something else from typings that I need to download to get this to work

There is a bug in the typings compiler for this. Its buggy in TypeScript `@types` system as well (issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9488)

I would just copy the `react-router` file + `history` file from DT manually (that's what I did at work too)

Comment: That's an unfortunate bug. I'd rather not have to add custom files to typings dependencies to get the definitions to work properly, so that way I don't have to store all the definitions in the github repo, and everyone could just run `typings install` when they clone/pull.

Comment: turns out you don't need to do that. See my answer.